# Is it smart to keep static files in memory in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, caching, nginx

When serving static files in Node I am simply using `fs.readFile` and then throwing the data onto the response content.

I am tempted to store the results of `fs.readFile` in a variable and then skip using `fs.readFile` when the file is requested a second time and just write the content out from the variable in memory.

My questions:

1. Are there any issues I could run into with this approach? Is there a better way?
2. (a high level overview) How do servers like nginx and Apache cache files to serve to users?

Comment: It is smart to serve static files with nginx.

Comment: Note that if you do want to cache files, you shouldn't convert them to strings.  Buffers exist outside the node.js heap.

Comment: ram is orders of magnitude faster than disks (less so to SSD). you can expect a large speedup on a busy server by transitioning to ram or even using a ramdisk to serve php and other semi-dynamic content. you can use node's fs.watch to observe a whole folder and auto-uncache changed paths.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any issues I could run into with this approach? Is there a better way?

Yep, you can run out of memory. You can keep in cache only what is hot.

> How do servers like nginx and Apache cache files to serve to users?

They keep it in memory indeed but additionally they implement some LRU (or LRU-alike) strategy to invalidate caches.

References:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Examples